# Prevent Windows 8 to close specific metro application in low memory situation?

Tags: windows-8

With Windows 8 Modern application, the system automatically closes metro applications when the available memory is low.

Is it possible to prevent this behavior for specific applications?

Basically, I'm using a music player ([Deezer](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/fr-fr/app/deezer/e48b595e-b20a-4eb3-968c-c20b2cadaa1e)), but the app is frequently killed by Windows.

I would like to raise this application priority, or white-list it, or whatever is possible to avoid music interruption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What sort of device are you using? If it's possible the best solution of course would be to buy more RAM.

I believe Win8 closes [suspended Metro/Modern UI apps](https://superuser.com/questions/503221/what-happens-to-modern-ui-apps-when-they-arent-in-the-foreground) first, and then apps that are performing background tasks such as [background audio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/05/16/being-productive-when-your-app-is-offscreen.aspx) when it runs low on memory. AFAIK there's no way to change the OS' default behaviour for specific or even all apps.

Perhaps what you can do is run Deezer in [snapped mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/all-about-apps?page=touch2#touch):

[image: 1]

Since this way it is one of the foreground apps it may run for longer without being terminated by the OS.

Comment: I d'un Windows 8 on my work laptop, which has 16 GB of ram. Hard to extend :/. If you wonder, I fill the memory with some hyper-v development VM

Comment: Well, can't really blame the OS. Its mem management routines are simply doing their job when available mem runs low. Also, isn't it better that an app like Deezer is killed, instead of your VM? ;) Anyway, try my suggestion for some time and see if it helps.